# How to map the dictionary values to another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary which is below

```
{
    "aggregations": { 
        "A": { 
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0, 
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0, 
            "buckets": [ 
                { "key": "ADL", "doc_count": 1 },
                { "key": "SDD", "doc_count": 1 }, 
                { "key": "JJD", "doc_count": 1 }
            ] 
        }, 
        "B": { 
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0, 
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0, 
            "buckets": [ 
                { "key": "ABC", "doc_count": 1 }, 
                { "key": "CDE", "doc_count": 1 }, 
                { "key": "FGH", "doc_count": 1 } 
            ] 
        }, 
        "C": { 
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0, 
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0, 
            "buckets": [ 
                { "key": "XYX", "doc_count": 1 }, 
                { "key": "NXS", "doc_count": 1 } 
            ] 
         } 
    }
}
```

- aggregations.keys will be aggregationfilters.fieldName
- aggregations.buckets.key will be aggregationfilters.values.title
- aggregationfilters.values.paragraph is null everytime
- aggregations.buckets.doc_count will be aggregationfilters.values.count
- Basically I need to extract aggregations.keys and aggregations.bucket values and put into different dictionary.

Need to write a general code structure to do that.

I cannot do with .pop(rename) the dictioanry

My expected out

```
{
    "aggregationfilters": [ 
        { 
            "name": "ABC", 
            "fieldName": "A", 
            "values": [ 
                { "title": "ADL", "paragraph": null, "count": 1 }, 
                { "title": "SDD", "paragraph": null, "count": 1 }, 
                { "title": "JJD", "paragraph": null, "count": 1 }
            ] 
        }, { 
            "name": "CDE", 
            "fieldName": "B", 
            "values": [ 
                { "title": "ABC", "paragraph": null, "count": 1 }, 
                { "title": "CDE", "paragraph": null, "count": 1 }, 
                { "title": "FGH", "paragraph": null, "count": 1 } 
            ] 
        }, { 
            "name": "FGH", 
            "fieldName": "C", 
            "values": [ 
                { "title": "XYX", "paragraph": null, "count": 1 }, 
                { "title": "NXS", "paragraph": null, "count": 1 }
            ] 
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: and where is your current code?

Comment: @Tibebes.M got error Sir, do i need to post the non work code?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this works, but even with my best effort this still doesn't look that clean.

```py
import json

source = {
    "aggregations": {
        "A": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {"key": "ADL", "doc_count": 1},
                {"key": "SDD", "doc_count": 1},
                {"key": "JJD", "doc_count": 1},
            ],
        },
        "B": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {"key": "ABC", "doc_count": 1},
                {"key": "CDE", "doc_count": 1},
                {"key": "FGH", "doc_count": 1},
            ],
        },
        "C": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [{"key": "XYX", "doc_count": 1}, {"key": "NXS", "doc_count": 1}],
        },
    }
}


convert_map = {
    "buckets": "values",
    "doc_count": "count",
    "key": "title",
}

remove_map = {"sum_other_doc_count", "doc_count_error_upper_bound"}

add_map = {"name": "Changed VAL_", "fieldName": "VAL_"}


def converting_generator(
    source_: dict, convert_map_: dict, remove_map_: set, add_map_: dict
):
    working_dict = {k: v for k, v in source_.items()}
    variable_identifier = "VAL_"

    for key, inner_dic in working_dict.items():
        inner_dic: dict
        for rm_key in remove_map_:
            try:
                inner_dic.pop(rm_key)
            except KeyError:
                pass

        for add_key, add_val in add_map_.items():
            inner_dic[add_key] = add_val.replace(variable_identifier, key)

        dumped = json.dumps(inner_dic, indent=2)

        for original, target in convert_map_.items():
            dumped = dumped.replace(original, target)

        yield json.loads(dumped)


converted = {
    "aggregation_filters": list(
        converting_generator(source["aggregations"], convert_map, remove_map, add_map)
    )
}

for inner_dict in converted["aggregation_filters"]:
    for even_inner_dict in inner_dict["values"]:
        even_inner_dict["paragraph"] = None

print(json.dumps(converted, indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "aggregation_filters": [
    {
      "values": [
        {
          "title": "ADL",
          "count": 1,
          "paragraph": null
        },
        {
          "title": "SDD",
          "count": 1,
          "paragraph": null
        },
        {
          "title": "JJD",
          "count": 1,
          "paragraph": null
        }
      ],
      "name": "Changed A",
      "fieldName": "A"
    },
    {
      "values": [
        {
          "title": "ABC",
          "count": 1,
          "paragraph": null
        },
        {
          "title": "CDE",
          "count": 1,
          "paragraph": null
        },
        {
          "title": "FGH",
          "count": 1,
          "paragraph": null
        }
      ],
      "name": "Changed B",
      "fieldName": "B"
    },
    {
      "values": [
        {
          "title": "XYX",
          "count": 1,
          "paragraph": null
        },
        {
          "title": "NXS",
          "count": 1,
          "paragraph": null
        }
      ],
      "name": "Changed C",
      "fieldName": "C"
    }
  ]
}
```

Always show your code, would be nice if that's a working one - to show that you've put at least that worth of the effort on your problem.

I don't bother it as this feels like puzzle solving, but others may not.

Comment: can you help me in writing below add_map = 
`{"aggregation_filters": [{
{"name": "ABC", "fieldName": "A", "values": []},
{"name": "CDE", "fieldName": "B", "values": []},
{"name": "FGH", "fieldName": "C", "values": []}
]}`

Comment: can you check once

Comment: Sorry for delay, I'm under military service and only have 4 hours access on pc, I'll check and update accordingly, tho.

Comment: @Nons I don't find any common calculation required to get output of *ABC CDE FGH*, please, put as much as detail possible and hopefully, a sample of real data you're working with. General purpose code is not possible without actual data to test with.